# Py2neo (V4) - CypherSyntaxError: Variable `$x` not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying in the absolute simplest way I can think of to create a node in my neo4j database using py2neo. Here is an example:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node

db = Graph()
node = Node('band', name='The Yeah Yeah Yeahs')
db.create(node)
```

With this (and every variation thereof), I get the following error:

```
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Variable `$x` not defined (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"UNWIND $x AS data CREATE (_:band) SET _ = data RETURN id(_)"
```

I've tried every permutation of this that I can think of and I still can't see anything in my code that might be causing a syntax error. This appears to be some kind of internal mechanism for generating a cypher query in order to create the node, but even with the complete stack trace I haven't been able to track down where this error might be coming from or what might be causing it.

I am using a virtual environment that uses Python 3.7.2 and py2neo 4.1.3.

Any thoughts or insights would be hugely appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Neo4j are you using? The `$x` replaced the older `{x}` syntax and the error message implies that `$x` isn't recognised. If this isn't a recent version, please try upgrading your database and try again.

Comment: Well heck. That's exactly what it was. I've downloaded and set up a new Neo4j 3.5.2 database using the desktop application (in lieu of the Neo4j Community Edition, which is what I was using before) and my code works like a charm now. Thanks so much for the helping hand!

Comment: Same happened to me; upgrade the database.  I was on docker and it wasn't obvious I was only on 3.0